# Two Types not equal that should be

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to debug some code that uses reflection to load plugins

Here's the debugging code:

```
Type a = methodInfo.GetParameters()[0]
    .ParameterType.BaseType;
Type b = typeof(MessageContext);
Debug.WriteLine(a.AssemblyQualifiedName);
Debug.WriteLine(b.AssemblyQualifiedName);
Debug.WriteLine(a.Equals(b));
```

And here is its output:

> OrtzIRC.Common.MessageContext, OrtzIRC.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>  
>   OrtzIRC.Common.MessageContext, OrtzIRC.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>   False

I don't understand what would make these two types different?

Comment: What does `.UnderlyingSystemType` return on both of them?

Comment: Well then. Were they loaded by different class loaders?

Comment: What I mean is, do you have a small stand-alone runnable sample that we can test with?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The same class / type loaded by different app domains [.NET] or class loaders [Java] will not compare equal and are not assignable to/from each other directly.

You likely have two copies of the DLL containing that type - one loaded by the main program and one loaded by one of the `Assembly.Load*(...)` methods?

Try displaying / comparing the properties:
`a.Assembly.Equals(b.Assembly)`
and
`a.Assembly.Location.Equals(b.Assembly.Location)`

In general, you only want one copy of each DLL and have it loaded into a single app domain.

Comment: You're right, it was loading two copies of the same assembly. One of them was being copied to the plugins directory and so I guess the plugin was loading that one instead of the one already in the app domain. So I just deleted the assembly and turned off "Copy local" and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar (if not the same) issue.  I noticed that despite being in different app domains, `Assembly.Load*` functions succeed in checking type equality but `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad*` functions fail.  I'd appreciate if you could check out my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40292593/975724

Comment: You helped me find the problem. My plugin has a type loaded from a plugin directory. I am comparing it to a type from the same dll loaded from Temporary ASP.NET Files. I don't know how to solve this yet, though. I need make the Temporary ASP.NET Files version go away.

Answer (score 3):

This can happen if the two types are loaded from different versions of the assembly. .NET considers them different, unrelated types. Check

```
Debug.WriteLine (a.AssemblyQualifiedName) ;
Debug.WriteLine (b.AssemblyQualifiedName) ;
```

Comment: Both are identical, same version.

Comment: Then it's probably assembly loader context: the `typeof()` assembly is loaded into the default context, but `Assembly.LoadFrom()` and friends load into the LoadFrom context. Again you get different types. The workaround is to check whether the assembly is already loaded into the appdomain before `LoadFrom()`'ing it.

Comment: *or* ensure that you load OrtzIRC.Common into the default context (`typeof(MessageContext)` should do) before you start loading plugins that refer to this assembly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should compare the types:

[C# Object Type Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708205/c-object-type-comparison)

I think your problem resides in the type hierarchy...

Answer (score 0):

Try: `Debug.Writeline(a.Equals(b));`